# When did 'wyrm' lose its meaning as dragon?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, semantics, semantic-shift, online-resources

I'm interested in finding out (roughly) when the Old English word 'wyrm' began to lose its meaning as 'A serpent, snake, dragon' due to the competing 'draca' and the later borrowing 'dragon'. I've consulted the OED but it suggests wyrm retains its meaning as 'dragon' until the 19th century, surely as an archaism. Can anyone could tell me approximately when draca and/or dragon became the popular choice to denote dragon

Comment: Hi Alison, welcome to ELU. I recommend you [edit] your post to remove the request for online tools, as such requests are off-topic. Instead of using such tools to research the issue, why not just ask us here for the answer? If you add a sentence or two explaining what sources you’ve already consulted (e.g. regarding the “competing *draca*”), this would be an **excellent** question! :-)

Comment: see also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34088/do-standard-definitions-exist-for-dragon-drake-wyrm-and-wyvern

Comment: As mentioned in the SciFi question user240918 linked to, Tolkien used _worm_ to mean ‘dragon’ in his (20th-century) writings. Granted, his writings are somewhat archaic, but not so archaic that they’re not generally immediately understandable. I would consider _worm_ in the sense ‘dragon’ to be archaising or perhaps archaic nowadays, but definitely not obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

According to the OED, *wyrm* (in the spelling *worm*) was first used to refer to the earthworm  and similar creatures in Middle English, and even in early use it seemed to refer to a wide range of creepy crawlies. The [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED53443/track?counter=1&search_id=799654) documents all of these meanings.

*Dragon* also emerged in Middle English as a loan word from French, transmitted through some combination of bestiaries, saints' lives like [St. Margaret's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_the_Virgin), Biblical translations, and romances. I would consult the [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED12521/track?counter=1&search_id=799654) quotations to see the sheer range of sources *dragon* appeared in.

Throughout Middle English the two terms coexisted, both referring to dragons. In the early modern period, the more modern meaning of *worm* has already taken over its earlier large and serpentine sense. The [Lexicons of Early Modern English database](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/search/quick) shows the dominance of *worm* referring to insects and *small* serpents even in early entries. In Latin-English dictionaries they are often *vermis*, Latin for the modern worm. By Samuel Johnson's Dictionary (1755) he defines "[worm](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/1345/42475)" primarily in this way:

> 1. A small harmless serpent that lives in the earth.
> 2. A poisonous serpent.

Then parasites, then silkworms, then grubs, and then more figurative senses. Wyrm is absent. In contrast, *dragon* even in the 16th century was the primary translation of draconic words. *[The Dictionary of Sir Thomas Elyot](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/63/9980)* (1538) glosses *draco*, *-onis* as "a dragon." Such usage continues down to Johnson's *Dictionary*, where "[dragon](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/1345/12141)" was defined in its modern meaning:

> 1. A kind of winged serpent, perhaps imaginary, much celebrated in the romances of the middle age.

So save in specialized or archaic uses, *dragon* outpaces the draconic sense of *worm* by the 16th century.

---

As someone who has studied medieval literature for a long time, my sense is that *worm* was fast diminishing in Middle English save in texts that hearkened back to Old English usage like the alliterative *Sir Gawain and the Green Knight* (late 14th c.), whereas *dragon* became the preferred expression in popular saints' lives and romances. I consulted a few popular sources and one database to work through this hypothesis:

(1) Sir Thomas Malory's ***Le Morte D'Arthur*** (written ~1470, printed 1485), the Arthurian romance seminal to 19th and 20th century adaptations of King Arthur and his knights, features the *dragon* at several key points, including in a dream King Arthur has before fighting a giant. I'm writing from the Winchester MS and updating the spelling but not the syntax:

> As the King was in his cog and lay in his cabin, he fell in a slumbering and dreamed how a dreadful **dragon** did drench much of his people, and come flying on wing
> out of the west parts. ...

*Dragon* occurs several times throughout the story. *[Worm](https://books.google.com/books?id=DYcaAQAAMAAJ&dq=concordance%20to%20Malory&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=worm)* and *[wyrm](https://books.google.com/books?id=DYcaAQAAMAAJ&dq=concordance%20to%20Malory&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=wyrm)* never appear. A later epic romance, Edmund Spenser's *Faerie Queene* (1590, 1596) fits the same pattern: *[dragon](https://books.google.com/books?id=iWTepQNJYVcC&dq=faerie%20queene%20concordance&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=dragon)* appears 13 times and *[worm](https://books.google.com/books?id=iWTepQNJYVcC&dq=faerie%20queene%20concordance&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=worm)* only appears as "gealouse worme" and "worm-eaten." That's remarkable, since the Redcrosse Knight defeats a dragon at the end of book 1, so there was a perfect opportunity to fight a *worm*, but Spenser never chose that word for that purpose.

(2) The ***Wycliffe Bible*** are an early complete translation of the Bible completed by religious reformers under the direction of John Wycliffe. **[Dragon](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=dragon&qs_version=WYC)** appears 47 times and usually refers to serpents or monsters:

> (Revelation 12) : And another sign was seen in heaven; and lo! a great red dragon, that had seven heads [having seven heads], and ten horns, and in the heads of him seven diadems.

**Worm** appears 33 times, usually referring to small creatures:

> (Isaiah 51:8) : For why a worm shall eat them so as a cloth, and a moth shall devour them so as wool; but mine health shall be without end, and my rightfulness into generations of generations.

So even around 1400 a series of translators were distinguishing worms and dragons.

(3) An [Early English Books Online search for both worm/wyrm and dragon](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?ALLSELECTED=1;xc=1;g=eebogroup;type=boolean;rgn=works;q1=worm;op2=or;q2=wyrm;op3=and;q3=dragon;singlegenre=All;c=eebo;c=eebo2;view=reslist;subview=short;sort=occur;start=1;size=25) yields over 1500 results. I've looked at the first several, and so far the words appear to not overlap in meaning. Now, that doesn't preclude *worm* referring to large serpents in some specialized or literary uses, but even the OED entries for Shakespeare and Milton refer to small serpents. I can find no association with anything dragon-like in English after 1500, suggesting that the association after that point is *rare* or intentionally *archaic*:

> a1616   Shakespeare Antony & Cleopatra (1623) v. ii. 238   Hast thou the pretty worme of Nylus there, That killes and paines not?
>
> 1667   Milton Paradise Lost ix. 1068   O Eve, in evil hour thou didst give eare To that false Worm .

Answer (score 1):

According to Etymologyonline:

***dragon*** was borrowed in the middle of the 13 century, 
from Old French dragon and directly from Latin draconem 
(nominative draco) "huge serpent, dragon".

Here's a quotation from the Middle English text of 1275:

*St.Marg.(2) (Trin-C B.14.39)

"Ho sei a foul dragun ine þe hurne glide, berninde ase fur."

https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/bibliography/BIB3314?rid=hyp.677.19990304t151115)

According to the above-mentioned Middle English Dictionary,
"worm" was a polysemantic noun from 1275 to 1500.

The example of ''worm'' in the modern meaning is also quoted in 1250-1275:

c1275(?c1250) Owl & N.(Clg A.9)
601 : Ac wat etestu…Bute attercoppe & fule uliʒe, An wormes, ʒif þu miʒte finde Among þe uolde of harde rinde

Comment: That doesn’t really say anything about when _worm_ stopped being used to refer to serpents or dragons, though; the two coexisted in that sense for quite a long time.